# Open Subgroup of (R,+)

Tags: group-theory, metric-spaces

Let G be an open subgroup of (R,+)

Show that G=R.

Note: I've tried taking an interior point of G. Can Archimedian Property be used?

Comment: And what happened when you tried that?

Comment: for 0 being an interior point of G there exits R>0 such that (-R,R) is in G! take any ponit P in (-R,R) nP is in G(n stands for natural number). for any x in R there exists natural number m such tha mP<=x<(m+1)P and then?

Answer (score 6):

The cosets of an open subgroup are open, so the set of cosets gives you partition of $R$ into non-empty open sets.

But $R$ is connected...

Comment: I haven't studied connectedness as yet! :(

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**

Suppose that $G$ is an open subgroup, then there is some $x\in\Bbb R$ such that $(-x,x)\subseteq G$. Therefore for any $y\in G$ we have $(-x+y,x+y)\subseteq G$. Conclude that every $r\in\Bbb R$ can be found in such translation and therefore $G=\Bbb R$.

Comment: How to show every r in R is there in the translation?

Comment: @MAB: Try first with some test case. What if $x=y=1$? Can you show that in this case? Now try and see how the general case follows from that.

Comment: In fact, you only need a set of positive measure not even an interval. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus_theorem